# Database on iMac

Tags: database, macos, filemaker

I want to create a database on my iMac in order to store contacts aswell as other data in a structured hierarchy.. i need to be able to access and add/edit/delete entries on this database from external devices (iPad, iPhone, macbook, other computers, etc) via WIFi (i.e. when an ipad is connected to the wireless network that the server is on, it should be able to edit the databases)

Having researched the topic I have only found one possible software that i could use.. It is called filemaker server.

http://www.filemaker.com/products/filemaker-server/

What i wish to know is whether there are any other suitable alternatives to filemaker?

Comment: If you are willing to do some coding, then another alternative is to use a database such as mysql (free) and build a webpage that is hosted in your iMac to perform the necessary Add/Edit/Delete operations.

Comment: Thank you for the response.. the aim is to have the data available in house and not on the internet.. i know i could protect the server, etc but its seems a little long winded.. simply put i want to hold a database of tables on my imac, and access/edit them from an ipad that is connected to the same wireless network.. it saves me the hassle of running up and down with pieces of paper and adding them manually on the imac..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "as well as other data in a structured hierarchy" It's a bit all-encompassing? ;-)

If cost is the issue then, have you thought about using [Apple's Server](http://www.apple.com/macosx/server/) software? It should be cheap as chips ($49) when Lion ships, and it includes wikis, shared contacts etc. editable via a web interface.

However, for ease of use, FileMaker server is hard to beat. It works out of the box, across Macs, iOS devices (using FileMaker Go) and even over the web (although for that you'll need the FileMaker Pro advanced version.

Otherwise, you're looking at OpenSource mysql/php based software solutions which are platform agnostic, and will work in any browser. If you do go this route, look at getting [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html) to do the heavy lifting - makes setting up the PHP and MySQL stuff a doddle.

Comment: soory i can see how "as well as other data in a structured hierarchy" isnt clear.. basically looking to have tables of contacts and group them specific to what type of contacts they are.. ideally should be able to query these tables in different ways when trying to locate a specific contact..
But thank you for the reply, you've given me a bit more optimism about investing in filemaker .. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need not purchase Server if you're going to have 9 or less remote devices connecting. Note that you must keep a copy of FileMaker Pro running (with your databases open) in order to serve these remote connections. Server is far more robust and allows for hundreds of clients with better admin capabilities for automated backups but comes at a steeper price. You still need to purchase client copies regardless of hosting via FM Pro or FM Server.

Comment: If you are using iOS devices as clients, then you can use Filemaker Go, an attractive possibility.

Comment: As someone who is in the midst of a filemaker trial, it is one of the most aggravating chunks of software I've ever used.  Scripts are retro, reminiscent of COBOL, everything is mouse driven, including script writing, it next to impossible to extract debugging information, and I have no idea how to document your database short of endless screen shots.